# android custom view obtainStyledAttributes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm pretty new to Android and to Java so forgive me if i'm missing something obvious.

I want to write a custom View, and i have problems getting the custom attributes via otainStyledAttributes.
I have a very simple testcase.
In Eclipse i create an empty project (package com.example.customview) with the default activity.
Then i added  an "attrs.xml" file under res/values with the following content:

```
  <resources>
    <declare-styleable name="testview">
       <attr name="test" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
  </resources>
```

then i add a new class "testview.java" in a new package "com.example.views".

```
package com.example.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.customview.R;

public class testview extends LinearLayout{

  public testview(Context context,AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context,attrs);

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    this.addView(tv);
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.testview, 0, 0);

    tv.setText(a.getString(R.styleable.testview_test));

    a.recycle();

}
}
```

and finally in activity_main.xml i have:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.views.testview
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" 
        my:test="test"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i am able to get the my:test attribute with

```
attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customview","test")
```

but that also works if i put the attribute in any random namespace.

but a.getString(R.styleable.testview_test) is allways null.

Comment: Sorry, i just realised that a.getString(R.styleable.testview_test) is only null during designtime but works great in runtime.

Comment: and remove this also  android:text="@string/hello_world"

Comment: null in runtime for me